# cannot access private member declared in class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, private

I've got piece of code, it's method definition

```
Move add(const Move & m) {
    Move temp;
    temp.x+= (m.x +this-x);
    temp.y+= (m.y + this->y);
    return temp;
}
```

and this is class declaration

```
class Move
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
public:
    Move(double a=0,double b=0);
    void showMove() const;
    Move add(const Move & m) const;
    void reset(double a=0,double b=0);
};
```

It says that

```
1>c:\users\filip\dysk google\c++\consoleapplication9\move.cpp(18): error C2248: 'Move::x' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Move'
1>          c:\users\filip\dysk google\c++\consoleapplication9\move.h(7) : see declaration of 'Move::x'
1>          c:\users\filip\dysk google\c++\consoleapplication9\move.h(5) : see declaration of 'Move'
1>          c:\users\filip\dysk google\c++\consoleapplication9\move.h(7) : see declaration of 'Move::x'
1>          c:\users\filip\dysk google\c++\consoleapplication9\move.h(5) : see declaration of 'Move'
1>c:\users\filip\dysk google\c++\consoleapplication9\move.cpp(18): error C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member functions
1>c:\users\filip\dysk google\c++\consoleapplication9\move.cpp(18): error C2227: left of '->x' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

and same for Move::y . Any1 has idea whats that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define `add` in the `Move` class scope:

```
Move Move::add(const Move & m) const {
    Move temp;
    temp.x+= (m.x +this-x);
    temp.y+= (m.y + this->y);
    return temp;
}
```

Otherwise it is interpreted as a non member function, with no access to `Move`'s non public members.

Note that you can simplify the code, assuming the two parameter constructor sets `x` and `y`:

```
Move Move::add(const Move & m) const {
    return Move(m.x + this-x, m.y + this->y);
}
```